# Allennlp: AttributeError: 'zipimport.zipimporter' object has no attribute 'path'

Tags: python-module, allennlp

when trying to run AllenNLP train command, I ran into this Error.

> 2021-02-25 02:57:40,043 - INFO - allennlp.common.plugins - Plugin allennlp_models available
>
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >
> > > File "/home/zliu60/miniconda/envs/sftp-env/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
> > > "**main**", mod_spec)
> > > File "/home/zliu60/miniconda/envs/sftp-env/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
> > > exec(code, run_globals)
> > > File "/home/zliu60/miniconda/envs/sftp-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/**main**.py", line 38, in 
> > > run()
> > > File "/home/zliu60/miniconda/envs/sftp-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/**main**.py", line 34, in run
> > > main(prog="allennlp")
> > > File "/home/zliu60/miniconda/envs/sftp-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/**init**.py", line 117, in main
> > > import_module_and_submodules(package_name)
> > > File "/home/zliu60/miniconda/envs/sftp-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/common/util.py", line 351, in import_module_and_submodules
> > > if path_string and module_finder.path != path_string:
> > > AttributeError: 'zipimport.zipimporter' object has no attribute 'path'

It seems like this is an allennlp related issue, but I don't know which part in my code (whether config file or modules) or the environment this is related to. Could someone please help me.

Comment: Hi, can you open a github issue in the allennlp repository?

Comment: The issue is here: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues/5532